# Error in Angular routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can you help me please? I try to render page with AngularJS. Page has been rendered, but in console of browser it give me error.

**app.js** (main angular file)

```
var DevApp = angular.module("DevApp", [ 'ngRoute' ])

.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl/index.html', controller: "MainCtrl" })
    .otherwise({
            url: '/',
            controller: "MainCtrl",
            templateUrl: "tpl/index.html"
        });
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$routeParams',
    '$element',
    '$timeout',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $element, $timeout) {
        console.log(1);
    }
]);
```

**tpl/index.html** (temppate of MainCtrl)

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Главная страница
</div>
```

**index.html** (main file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DevApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/angular/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I receive error:

```
angular.js:12416
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24elementProvider%20%3C-%20%24element%20%3C-%20MainCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:40:307
    at Object.d [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:38:308)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:40:381
    at d (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:38:308)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:39:64)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:39:213)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular.min.js:80:257
    at link (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/angular/angular-route.js:977:26) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: What does  `$element` and `$timeout` signify in controller parameters?

Comment: I wrote this code by examples. 
Now I delete $element and $timeot, and it works! 
But I can't understand why code did not worked.

Comment: You are injecting $element service to the controller. So when you want to use the $element, you need this service should be available when controller loads..

Comment: $timeout service is available in angular.min.js plugin itself. So you no need to delete that one.

Comment: $element service is not available, you have to define it. All other services are provided by angular.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my problem

Comment: @JohnV You should mark an answer as accepted if helped.

Answer (score 1):

`Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- MainCtrl`, which means that the `$element` could not be injected in your `MainCtrl`.

Comment: You've run faster than me to reply :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var DevApp = angular.module("DevApp", [ 'ngRoute' ])

DevApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl/index.html', controller: "MainCtrl" })
    .otherwise({
            url: '/',
            controller: "MainCtrl",
            templateUrl: "tpl/index.html"
        });
}])

DevApp.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$routeParams',
    '$element',
    '$timeout',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $element, $timeout) {
        console.log(1);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test your code but maybe there is typo in the router declaration ( there is no 'url' param )

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl/index.html', controller: "MainCtrl" })
    otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}])
```